# Locate position of first number in string [R]

Tags: r, string, locate

How can I create a function in R that locates the word position of the first number in a string?

For example:

```
string1 <- "Hello I'd like to extract where the first 1010 is in this string"
#desired_output for string1
9

string2 <- "80111 is in this string"
#desired_output for string2
1

string3 <- "extract where the first 97865 is in this string"
#desired_output for string3
5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to return your desired output:

```
library(stringr)
min(which(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(str_split(string, " ", simplify = TRUE))))))
```

This is how it works:

```
str_split(string, " ", simplify = TRUE) # converts your string to a vector/matrix, splitting at space

as.numeric(...) # tries to convert each element to a number, returning NA when it fails

suppressWarnings(...) # suppresses the warnings generated by as.numeric

!is.na(...) # returns true for the values that are not NA (i.e. the numbers)

which(...) # returns the position for each TRUE values

min(...) # returns the first position
```

The output:

```
min(which(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(str_split(string1, " ", simplify = TRUE))))))
[1] 9
min(which(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(str_split(string2, " ", simplify = TRUE))))))
[1] 1
min(which(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(str_split(string3, " ", simplify = TRUE))))))
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 5):

I would just use `grep` and `strsplit` here for a base R option:

```
sapply(input, function(x) grep("\\d+", strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]))

Hello I'd like to extract where the first 1010 is in this string
                                                               9
                                         80111 is in this string
                                                               1
                 extract where the first 97865 is in this string
                                                               5
```

**Data:**

```
input <- c("Hello I'd like to extract where the first 1010 is in this string",
           "80111 is in this string",
           "extract where the first 97865 is in this string")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, it just searches for specified text ```1010```

Comment: @NealBarsch Check the update, sorry, I didn't realize you wanted to search for _any_ number.  I only needed to make a slight change to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. We can trim off the remaining characters after the first digit of the first number. Then, just find the position of the last word. `\\b` matches word boundaries while `\\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters.

```
first_numeric_word <- function(x) {
  x <- substr(x, 1L, regexpr("\\b\\d+\\b", x))
  lengths(gregexpr("\\b\\S+\\b", x))
}
```

Output

```
> first_numeric_word(x)
[1] 9 1 5
```

Data

```
x <- c(
  "Hello I'd like to extract where  the first 1010 is in this string", 
  "80111 is in this string", 
  "extract where the   first  97865 is in this string"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll leave a fully `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

map_dbl(str_split(strings, " "), str_which, "\\d+")
#> [1] 9 1 5

map_dbl(str_split(strings[1], " "), str_which, "\\d+")
#> [1] 9
```

Note that it works both with one and multiple strings.

---

Where `strings` is:

```
strings <- c("Hello I'd like to extract where the first 1010 is in this string",
             "80111 is in this string",
             "extract where the first 97865 is in this string")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
library(stringr)

position_first_number <- function(string) {
  min(which(str_detect(str_split(string, "\\s+", simplify = TRUE), "[0-9]+")))
}
```

With your example strings:

```
> string1 <- "Hello I'd like to extract where the first 1010 is in this string"
> position_first_number(string1)
[1] 9
 
> string2 <- "80111 is in this string"
> position_first_number(string2)
[1] 1
 
> string3 <- "extract where the first 97865 is in this string"
> position_first_number(string3)
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base solution using `rapply()` w/ `grep()` to recurse through the results of `strsplit()` and works with a vector of strings.

Note: swap `" "` and `fixed = TRUE` with `"\\s+"` and `fixed = FALSE` (the default) if you want to split the strings on any whitespace instead of a literal space.

```
rapply(strsplit(strings, " ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) grep("[0-9]+", x))
[1] 9 1 5
```

**Data**:

```
strings = c("Hello I'd like to extract where the first 1010 is in this string", 
            "80111 is in this string", "extract where the first 97865 is in this string")
```

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen, if I am honest, I am not completely sure what you mean. Can you clarify?